# Is it possible to suppress the "is your code coverage, take a quick tour" dialog?

Tags: code-coverage, tag, ideas

It seems like every time I visit the Apex Text Execution page, I get a yellow popup asking me to go on a tour of the apex test system. After taking the tour four or five times, I kind of got sick of it. So now I just say "no thanks".

Still, it pops up *all the time*. Is there any way to suppress that nag?

Comment: I found using the No Thanks button would cause the dialog to reappear with the next login. However, if I jumped through the 3 steps of the tour it wouldn't appear again even after logging out and then in again.

Comment: This should be an idea. I would upvote it.

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger can you please add that as answer so that this question will not appear in Unanswered question list. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found using the No Thanks button would cause the dialog to reappear with the next login. However, if I jumped through the 3 steps of the tour it wouldn't appear again even after logging out and then in again.